# Decoding Base 64 In Groovy Returns Garbled Characters

Tags: groovy, encoding, base64

I'm using an API which returns a Base64 encoded file that I want to parse and harvest data from. I'm having trouble decoding the Base64, as it comes back with garbled characters. The code I have is below.

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64()
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(Requests.getInventory(app).toString())
String stockB64 = json.getAt("stock")

byte[] decoded = decoder.decode(stockB64)
println(new String(decoded, "US-ASCII"))
```

I've also tried `println(new String(decoded, "UTF-8"))` and this returns the same garbled output. I've pasted in an example snipped of the output for reference.

```
�      ���v��� 
��W`�C�:�f��y�z��A��%J,S���}qF88D q )��'�C�c�X��������+n!��`nn���.��:�g����[��)��f^���c�VK��X�W_����������?4��L���D�������i�9|�X��������\���L�V���gY-K�^����
��b�����~s��;����g���\�ie�Ki}_������
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Base64` class wherever you took it from. You can simply do `stockB64.decodeBase64()` to get the `decoded` byte array. Are you sure what you have there is actual text that is encoded. Usually base64 encoded means that this is some binary like an image. If it is text you could have put it as string in the json simply. Maybe save the resulting byte array to a file and then investigate the file type by content.

Comment: I tried with `stockB64.decodeBase64()` previously and got the same output. The API documentation says it's a base64 encoded gzipped CSV file. I might have misunderstood the nature of the output, thinking I had to decode tye output, then unzip the file and write it to my filesystem. I'm away from my PC just now but I'll try just saving the output as a file and see what happens.

Comment: Well great, you have your answer. "base64 encoded gzipped file" means if you base64-decoded it, you have as a result a "gzipped file". Of course you cannot transform this into a String. gunzip the `byte[]` with a `GZIPInputStream`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's what happens when you stare at a problem for so long! I'll try that when I get back on the PC and mark this as the answer if all goes well!